# Heredar atributo con cambios - Python

Tags: python, poo

Hay alguna forma de heredar un atributo al que se le hace cambios en la clase madre?

```
class Madre_1:
    valor1 = 0
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor1 = valor

class Hija_1(Madre_1):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def imprimir(self):
        print("Valor de Madre_1: ", str(Madre_1.valor1))

madre = Madre_1(2)

hija = Hija_1()
hija.imprimir()
```

En este codigo heredo el atributo valor1, pero con el valor inicial (0). Como puedo heredarlo con el valor asignado (2) en el **init** de la clase madre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es más complejo de lo que piensas.

El atributo `valor1` de la clase `Madre_1` es un *atributo de clase*. La única forma de acceder a él es mediante la sintaxis `Madre_1.valor1`. Eso no es lo que haces en su constructor, en el que pones `self.valor1`. En este caso, a través de `self` no estás accediendo al atributo de clase, sino al atributo de instancia.

Cuando haces

```
madre = Madre_1(2)
```

creas una instancia llamada `madre`. Esa instancia es la que es asignada al parámetro `self` cuando llamas a su constructor, por lo que cuando dentro de él hagas `self.valor1 = valor`, asignas el 2 a la instancia, es decir a `madre.valor1`, en lugar de a la clase, es decir a `Madre_1.valor` que sigue valiendo cero.

Si hubieras cambiado el atributo de clase en lugar del de instancia, podrías incurrir en nuevos problemas ya que ese cambio afecta a *todas* las instancias que tengas de esa clase (así como las de sus herederas, si no redefinen el atributo en los objetos, via `self`). No sé si es ésto lo que quieres.

Es decir, imagina que tienes:

```
class Madre_1:
    valor1 = 0
    def __init__(self, valor):
        Madre_1.valor1 = valor

class Hija_1(Madre_1):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def imprimir(self):
        print("Valor de Madre_1: ", str(Madre_1.valor1))
```

Pues se daría la siguiente circunstancia:

```
>>> madre = Madre_1(2)       # Se cambia el atributo de clase a 2
>>> hija = Hija()
>>> hija.imprimir()
Valor de Madre_1:  2         # Hasta aqui todo bien
>>> otra_madre = Madre_1(5)  # Ahora las sorpresas...
>>> hija.imprimir()
Valor de Madre_1:  2         # Ha cambiado lo que muestra la hija previamente creada
>>> madre.valor1             # Y también la madre creada al principio!
```

Esto se debe a que cuando intentas leer `madre.valor1` estás intentando leer el atributo *de la instancia*, pero en este caso la instancia no tiene definido ese atributo, por lo que se sigue buscando a ver si su clase lo define como atributo de clase, y así es. Pero vale 5 ahora.

Y por si lo anterior fuese poco confuso, cada una de las instancias podría sobreescribir el atributo de clase con otro atributo de instancia, con el mismo nombre. Es decir, puedes hacer:

```
>>> hija.valor = 100
```

y esto crearía un atributo de valor 100 en esa hija, pero que no afecta a otras instancias (`madre` ni `otra_madre`) ni al valor del atributo de clase (`Madre_1.valor`).

Por todo lo anterior te diría. ¿Para qué necesitas esto exactamente? Quizás si explicas lo que intentas hacer se vea otra forma más sencilla.

Answer (score 1):

> En este codigo heredo el atributo valor1, pero con el valor inicial (0)

Esto es así porque es justamente lo que has programado. Si te fijas en el constructor de la clase `Hija_1`:

```
class Hija_1(Madre_1):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

No invoca a ningún constructor de la clase padre, en este caso `Madre_1`, luego el resultado es el esperado.

> Como puedo heredarlo con el valor asignado (2) en el init de la clase madre?

Debes llamar de forma explícita al constructor de la clase padre:

```
class Hija_1(Madre_1):
    def __init__(self):
        Madre_1.__init__(self, 2)
```

Claro que en Python 2 también se puede hacer así:

```
class Hija_1(Madre_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Hija_1, self).__init__(2)
```

Mientras que en Python 3 quedaría de esta otra forma:

```
class Hija_1(Madre_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(2)
```

`super()` es, en este caso, equivalente a `super(class, self)`

Comment: No lo arreglas con `super()`, porque el atributo de clase de `Madre_1` no se cambia de valor en ningún momento, lo que cambia de valor es el atributo de la instancia (`hija` en este caso, cuando es llamado a través de `super()`).